# Error en la llamada de una variable

Tags: python

Tengo los dos siguientes programas

1. Tracker.py: realiza los cálculos necesarios para apuntar una antena en azimut y elevación hacia un satélite
2. Menú.py: es la parte principal del programa y llama a muchos otros núcleos

Querría darle la capacidad al programa de discernir si el satélite está visible o no, declarando la condición (elevacion<0)
Sin embargo, a pesar de hacer muchos intentos no estoy consiguiendo llamar al valor que quiero (visible=False)
Dejo los códigos aquí abajo:

```
    def Visible(self):
        
        self.set_epoch(time.time())
        
        if self.elevation()<0:
            self.visible = False
            return self.visible
        else:
            print("Satélite visible")
```

Menú.py

```
            
        elif opcion == 2:
            
            visible=Tracker.Tracker.Visible()
            if visible==False:
                print("Satélite no visible")
                satelite = Choose_Satellite.Choose_Satellite()
                print("Estos son los datos TLE del satélite seleccionado: %s \n" % satelite)
                tracker = Tracker.Tracker(satelite)
                
            
           
            try:
                tracker
                
                print ("\nComienzo seguimiento\n")
                while 1:
                    mensaje = tracker.Calculator()
                    cliente.Send_Data(mensaje)
                    time.sleep(1)
                    if keyboard.is_pressed('esc') or keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
                        print("Ha pulsado la tecla para parar")
                        break
                    
            except NameError:
                print("Debe definir antes un satelite")
                satelite = Choose_Satellite.Choose_Satellite()
                print("Estos son los datos TLE del satélite seleccionado: %s \n" % satelite)
                tracker = Tracker.Tracker(satelite)
```

Por lo tanto lo que estoy intentando hacer es declarar falso si la elevación es negativa y que el programa principal para que lo reconozca antes de fallar.

Comment: Por favor, reduce el código al mínimo necesario que demuestra el problema. Hay un montón de líneas que son irrelevantes a la problemática en cuestión.

Comment: Muy bien, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema está aquí:

```
    def Visible(self):
        self.set_epoch(time.time())
        if self.elevation()<0:
            self.visible = False
            return self.visible
        else:
            print("Satélite visible")
```

Si `self.elevation()<0:` entonces retornas el valor de `self.visible`, que es `False`, pero ¿qué ocurre en caso contrario?

En caso contrario no estás retornando nada, sino haciendo un `print()`. Cuando una función no retorna nada, retorna en realidad `None`. Si quien recibe el resultado lo usa en un contexto booleano (por ejemplo en un `if`) se interpretará como `False`.

Por tanto tu función nuca retorna `True`. La solución es sencilla:

```
    def Visible(self):
        self.set_epoch(time.time())
        if self.elevation()<0:
            self.visible = False
        else:
            self.visible = True
        return self.visible
```

Comment: Gracias, esto me ha solucionado el problema